# cx_Oracle can't connect to Oracle database after updating OS X to 10.9.2

Tags: python, macos, oracle

On OS X 10.9 and 10.9.1, the cx_Oracle works OK. But after I updated my system to OS X 10.9.2 yesterday, it cannot work. When connecting to Oracle database, DatabaseError is raised. And the error message is:

> ORA-21561: OID generation failed

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this on OS X but the general Linux solution is to add your hostname to /etc/hosts for the IP 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed with a simple edit to your hosts file.

- Find the name of your local-machine by running hostname in your local-terminal

  `$hostname`
- Edit your local hosts file

  `$vi /etc/hosts`

  assuming `$hostname` gives *local_machine_name* append it to your localhost ,

  `127.0.0.1       localhost       local_machine_name`

  press esc and type wq! to save

Cheers!